# Whats the easiest way to make a multi-boot UEFI Windows/Linux/Mac (Universal) DVD/BD?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8, multi-boot, blu-ray

I can find tons of programs to make such USBs, but some computers I work with (like an older netbook) won’t boot specific OSs from USB.

But I want to fill up a BD ROM disc with various forms of Linux, Windows, Android x86 and recovery tools... Where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [YUMI - Your Universal Multiboot Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). Granted this is made for a USB drive, but then use the same as above - I can't say for sure it'll work, but I think it will. You will need a USB drive (or blank partition) to install the GRUB files. Works with Windows and a bunch of other Linux installers and live CDs.

To create an ISO from a USB drive, you can use a tool like the one mentioned in the [Hak5 forum](https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/15567-convert-bootable-usb-to-iso/)

Comment: YUMI has an EFI boot mode?

Comment: I don't believe it is EFI/uEFI compatible as it stands. If you are looking to boot ISO files, this can for at least Windows 7 installers although I think it just uses the files from the CD to launch the installer. I use it on my primary USB key to reformat Windows XP and 7 PCs, as well as several ISOs and live CDs for diag.

Comment: YUMI now has a UEFI beta version that works well for USBs at least.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way based on what you already have is likely:

1. Create the USB version
2. Create an ISO from that USB
3. Burn the ISO to the disc

That said, if they don't support booting from a USB, I highly doubt they will support booting from a BD.

Comment: CD/DVD/BD is UDF?
USB is FAT32 (for bootable) yes?

Comment: USB is FAT 32 to boot, yes? can one make USB think it is real CD rom?

Answer (score 0):

Much time later...

I discovered the easiest way.

1. - Format USB as FAT 32.
2. - Use Winrar, 7zip to extract EFI capable ISO to Directory.
     (Like a windows 7/8/10 disk)
     (or a Linux Disk)
     [NOT a MAC Disk]
3. - Use a partition manager to toggle boot flag

But if a disk contains large files over 4096 megs, they wont work in fat32

For Mac Disks, Best to convert the disk to DMG, then use
A. Win32diskimager in windows (Its basically dd)
And just select the DMG (drop box "all files" first)
and click "write"

It will add the EFI partition, and the HFS+ parition to the USB, and it will boot.

This has worked for all the disks I needed.